# Monitor time spent by a user on different parts of an app

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Is it possible to monitor the percentage of time spent on different parts of my app (activities) in relation to the total usage duration? Are Events the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about `firebase`, but this is doable on `google-analytics`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Analytics doesn't have the possibility to monitor the percentage of time spent on different parts of an app. With events, you can count some actions, but not the time of the actions.

You can go with Google Analytics to get auto screen tracking and monitor time spent on screens.

**Update:**
Since [screen tracking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) has been added to Firebase Analytics it automatically tracks screens of an app if the app uses `Activity` for every screen. If your app doesn't, you can still get these reports by manually setting the screen name with the API.

Comment: Firebase has since added tracking of screen views to its Analytics. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this answer was provided 2 years ago, when Firebase wasn't supporting this

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Analytics doesn't have screen level user engagement reporting yet. We are considering adding support in one of the next releases.

If you need this earlier you can implement something similar yourself by listening to Activity onResult/onPause or [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html). You can record the time when the activity gains focus and log an event when the activity losses focus with the time spent.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @djabi said, Firebase do support overall app level user engagement.

[image]

However no screen / activity level data.

Comment: Where did you find this screen? I'm looking for the total time spent on the app for the past week

Answer (score 1):

On [version 11.0.0+](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_1), Firebase Analytics now automatically tracks the activities your users are on.

Whilst a brief summary is displayed on the `Analytics -> Dashboard` page, a much more detailed view can be seen by clicking the `View screen_view event details` link:

**Overview**:

[image: Activity usage overview]

**Detailed**:

[image: Activity usage detailed info]

*Note: If you wish to track fragments instead of activities, you'll need to select `Screen name` in the dropdown in the above screenshot. You'll also need to send `firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "myScreenName", null)` on fragment creation.*

[Further documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to track the amount of time a user spends on a particular screen in your app, you can designate a starting event (e.g. when the screen_view screen_name matches the screen you want to time, or when a button is tapped on the previous screen to get to the screen you want to time user activity upon) and then designate an ending event (e.g. the next screen_view matches the next screen_name, or the user taps a button to go to the next screen).

Set these up in a "funnel analysis" in your GA dashboard as two events that indirectly follow one another, flip the toggle to show elapsed time, and voila! Solved.

[image: funnel analysis setup with toggle elapsed time switch]

Comment: What if the user just exits the app instead of going to a new screen?