# how to track time engagement of user in the app in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I want to track the time engagement of users in the app that how much time each user spend in the app and send this time report to the admin through firebase in Flutter.

Need a detail code about this.

Comment: Check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753112/monitor-time-spent-by-a-user-on-different-parts-of-an-app

Comment: I don't want that firebase tracking system I wan to do it manually by programming